# Filter archive.php by custom meta

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, archives

I"m trying to filter an archive page by custom meta query.

I've tried using `query_posts($args)` prior to the loop, but it returns nothing.
Any ideas?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php 
        //$wolfName = $_GET['wolfName'];
        $archiveArgs = array(
                        'meta_key'  => 'wolf',
                        'meta_value'    => 'boltz'
                        );
        query_posts($archiveArgs);
        ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
```

It returns no posts... any ideas?

Comment: Check here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `pre_get_posts` action hook

```
function archive_meta_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_archive){
      $query->query_vars["meta_key"] = 'wolf';
      $query->query_vars["meta_value"] = 'boltz';
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'archive_meta_query', 1 );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for ur code   Strik3r ..this helped me a lot..I finally got sorting by custom field to work...in functions.php

```
function sort_meta_query( $query ) {
 if ( $query->is_archive || $query->is_category || $query->is_home ){
  $query->query_vars["meta_key"] = 'fastest_speed_experienced';
  $query->query_vars["orderby"] = 'meta_value_num';
 }
}
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sort_meta_query', 1 );
```